# Find the matrix of a linear transformation given kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the matrix associated to a linear function:

$ F: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^4 $

$ \ker F=\left\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x - 2y + z = 0\right\} $

and

$F((0,1,1))=(-1,-3,0,1)$

It's a multiple choice exercise, the possible answers are:

$ a = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -2 & 1 \\
  2 & -4 & 2 \\
  0 & 0 & 0  \\
 3 & -6 & 3 
 \end{pmatrix}$

$ b = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -2 & 1 \\
  2 & -4 & 2 \\
  0 & 0 & 0  \\
 -3 & 6 & -3 
 \end{pmatrix}$

$ c = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -2 & 1 \\
  3 & -6 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0  \\
 -1 & 2 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}$

$ d = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  2 & -2 & 1 \\
  4 & -6 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0  \\
 2 & 2 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}$

I don't know ho to proceed, can someone help me?

Comment: What is $L$? Do you mean $F$?

Comment: There is not **the** matrix associated with a linear map, but **a** matrix with respect to some choice of basis both in the domain of definitin and in the codomain.

Comment: @Misakov indeed

Comment: @DonAntonio that makes sense actually since the exercise is a multiple choice. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take the most basic, elementary way I can think of.

First, we work all the time with the standard basis in both domain and codomain.

Second, since $\;F(0,1,1)=(-1,-3,0,1)\;$, this means both (a)-(b) are ruled out at once, so we're left only with (c)-(d).

Also, option (d) has rank two (Gauss reduction) and thus its kernel's dimension is one (Dimensions' Theorem), so this does *not* fit the given data.

Finally, observe that (c) has rank equal to one, which means its image has dimension one and its kernel has dimension two (Dimensions' Theorem), which fits the data.

Comment: thank you. Why can't the kernel dimension be 1?

Comment: @guidev Because **the given** $\;\ker F\;$ is a two dimensional subspace: it is the solution set to *one* homogeneous linear equation in *three* variables...

Answer (score 2):

Let's call $M$ one matrix associated to $F$.

We know that $F(v) = 0$ for any $v \in \ker(F)$.

This means that each row of $M$ is orthogonal to any vector $v \in \ker(F)$.

A basis of $\ker(F)$ is:

$$k_1 = (2,1,0), k_2 = (-1,0,1).$$

It's easy to see that the vector $h = (1, -2, 1)$ is orthogonal to each vector of the basis of the kernel of $F$. Then any vector proportional to $h$ is orthogonal to any vector $v \in \ker(F)$. 
Then we can write the matrix $M$ as follows:

$$M = \pmatrix{
a & -2a & a \\
b & -2b & b \\
c & -2c & c \\
d & -2d & d
},$$

for some real numbers $a, b, c$ and $d$.

Moreover, we know that $F((0,1,1)) = (-1,-3,0,1)$. Then:

$F((0,1,1)) = (-a, -b, -c, -d) = (-1,-3,0,1),$ or equivalently

$$\begin{cases}
a = 1 \\
b = 3 \\
c = 0 \\
d = -1
\end{cases}$$

yielding to the matrix

$$M = \pmatrix{
1 & -2 & 1 \\
3 & -6 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1
}.$$

The answer is the matrix $c$.

Answer (score 0):

You can start choosing a basis for $ker F$, for instance $\{(1,0,-1),(2,1,0)\}$ and complete it to a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ adding $(0,1,1)$; so we have $\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb R^3}=\{(1,0,-1),(2,1,0),(0,1,1)\}$.  Now you have to choose a basis for $\Bbb R^4$, for instance $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(-1,-3,0,1)\}$.

Now: $F(1,0,-1)=F(2,1,0)=(0,0,0)$, and $F(0,1,1)=(-1,-3,0,1)$, then the matrix associate to $F$ with respect to those basis is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

EDIT: As DonAntonio said on its comment, this is not the unique matrix associate to $F$, but it depend on the choice of the basis.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $ker(F)=\left\langle (1, 0, -1), (0,1,2)  \right\rangle$ (why?) and also notice that (1,0-1)  and  (0,1,2) are linearly independent therefore using the Dimension Theorem :

$$3=dim(\mathbb R^3)=dim(ker(F))+dim(Im(F))=2+dim(Im(F)) \Rightarrow dim(Im(F))=1$$ 
now let B={(0,1,1),(1, 0, -1), (0,1,2)} , B is L.I and $B \subseteq \mathbb R^3$ therefore B is basis of $\mathbb R^3$ (why?)

so the only thing left to do will be to write the matrix of F with respect to base basis B as: $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
         |& | & | \\
        [F((0,1,1))]^t & [F((1,0,1-1)]^t & [F((0,1,2))]^t \\
         |& | & | \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ knowing that (1, 0, -1) and (0,1,2) are in the kernel. I hope that helps!